# Printing a pointer after its deletion prints null between parentheses

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, binary-search-tree

I wrote a piece of code that recursively finds the smallest string in a tree and deletes it. However, printing the tree after deleting the node returns (null).

```
static char* findMinimum(TreeNodePtr treePtr){
  if(treePtr->left == NULL){
    printf("Minimum node is %s\n", treePtr->item);
    char * temp = treePtr->item;
    (treePtr)->item = NULL;
    return(temp);
  }
  else{
    findMinimum(treePtr->left);
  }
}
```

I THINK this function works since it deletes the minimum value even using different strings. Should I write a condition to make sure NULL pointers won't get printed? Just in case, here's the print function as well:

```
static void printTree(TreeNodePtr treePtr) {
  if (treePtr != NULL) {
    level++;
    printTree(treePtr->left);
    printf(">%*s%s\n", level*5, "", treePtr->item);
    printTree(treePtr->right);
    level--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's say that to one of the parent node there is no left child, your code (is supposed to) deletes the parent node then what if there is a right child present?  How do you handle that? **PLUS** I guess `item` must be a string then what will assigning it to `NULL` will do?

Answer (score 1):

I see couple of problems in your `findMinimum` function:

1) What do you return in else-case in `findMinimum`? I guess you forgot to add `return`:

```c
static char* findMinimum(TreeNodePtr treePtr){
  if(treePtr->left == NULL){
    printf("Minimum node is %s\n", treePtr->item);
    char * temp = treePtr->item;
    (treePtr)->item = NULL;
    free(treePtr->item);
    return(temp);
  }
  else{
    return findMinimum(treePtr->left);  // added return
  }
}
```

2) Is your tree a binary search tree? Consider what happens in this case:

```
   root-node
   /       \ 
smallest   largest
    \
   not-smallest
```

You should rehang `not-smallest` node instead of `smallest`.

3) Why do you free `NULL`?

```c
(treePtr)->item = NULL;
free(treePtr->item);
```

Comment: 2) I think it is, what do you mean by rehang? 3) That made so little sense I edited the original post.

Comment: @Impasse 2) That `not-smallest` node should be the left child of `root-node`

Comment: @user3365922 No he is correct. The not-smallest has nothing common with the smallest string.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you should remove the `smallest` node, how tree will look like in this case?

Comment: @user3365922 He is not removing the whole node. He is deleting the string itself that is stored in the node.

Answer (score 0):

You're deleting the smallest node without changing the child of its parent. If you delete a node, you should also change its parent to point to NULL. Note that setting `treePtr->item` to NULL doesn't accomplish this as `treePtr->left` points to a TreeNodePtr, not to its `item` member.

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
static char* findMinimum(TreeNodePtr treePtr){
  if(treePtr->left == NULL){
    printf("Minimum node is %s\n", treePtr->item);
    char * temp = treePtr->item;
    (treePtr)->item = NULL;
    free(treePtr->item);
    return(temp);
  }
  else{
    findMinimum(treePtr->left);
  }
}
```

does not make sense.

For starters this part or the code

```
  else{
    findMinimum(treePtr->left);
  }
```

returns nothing. So the function already have undefined behavior.

Also consider these statements

```
    (treePtr)->item = NULL;
    free(treePtr->item);
```

The call of free does nothing.

Otherwise if you will exchange the statements when the function returns a pointer to already deleted string. And again the progarm will have undefined behavior.

Also it is unclear how the function will behave when it will be called the second time when the smallest string was already deleted.

And you have to dynamically create a copy of the smallest string that will be returned from the function.

I would suggest the following function implementation (without testing).

```
static char * findMinimum( TreeNodePtr treePtr )
{
    if ( treePtr == NULL || treePtr->item == NULL ) return NULL;

    if ( treePtr->left == NULL || treePtr->left->item == NULL )
    {
        char *s = malloc( strlen( treePtr->item ) + 1 );
        strcpy( s, treePtr->item );

        free( treePtr->item );
        treePtr->item = NULL;

        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        return findMinimum( treePtr->left );
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't calling the function like that necessary to achieve recursion? I know no other way to do that as of now. About the second part, gonna fix that. EDIT: just realized what you meant, whoops

Comment: @Impasse As I wrote the function has undefined behavior. If the first node does not contain the minimal string then the control is passed to the next left node and the function returns nothing.